# Oracle Query Performance -- Multiple Complex Window Functions

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

This query has been the bane of my existence. It's on a table with about 600 million rows. The table is not partitioned or indexed.

I have 24 tables of this data for historical trending. I had to adjust the code and now need to rerun. Each month takes 2-3 hours to run. I just recently tried to run 24 queries at once.. and my DBAs.. were not happy (bogged down entire DB)

I've tried partitioning and indexing but don't see increased performance.  I've tried different approaches of different levels of CTE.. or sub selects.. no luck... because of gaps in the UCIDs/CALLIDS .. there is a lot of time logic going on here..

```
    WITH
  UCID
  AS
    (SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) */
      --REGULAR FIELDS
      SEGSTART + (DISPTIME / 86400) CALLSTART
     ,SEGSTART +
      ((DISPTIME + ANSHOLDTIME + talktime) / 86400) +
      NvL(
        (CASE
           WHEN ORIGLOGIN IS NOT NULL AND
                ANSLOGIN IS NULL
           THEN
             (CONSULTTIME + ORIGHOLDTIME) / 86400
         END)
       ,0) CALLSTOP
     -- +NvL((cASE WHEN ORIGLOGIN IS NOT NULL AND ANSLOGIN IS NULL THEN CONSULTTIME/86400 END),0)CALLSTOP
     ,SEGSTART
     ,SEGSTOP
     ,split1
     ,UCID
     ,DIALED_NUM
     ,CALLING_PTY
     ,TRANSFERRED
     ,CALL_DTL_REC_ID
     ,CMSHOST COMPLEX_CMSHOST
     ,CALLID COMPLEX_CALLID
     ,anslogin n_anslogin
     ,origlogin n_origlogin
     --UCID WINDOW MATCHES
     ,LAST_VALUE(a.ASAIUUI)
        IGNORE NULLS
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY UCID
                      ,SEGSTART) ASAIUUI
     ,LAST_VALUE(a.ORIGLOGIN)
        IGNORE NULLS
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY UCID
                      ,SEGSTART) ORIGLOGIN
     ,LAST_VALUE(a.ANSLOGIN)
        IGNORE NULLS
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY UCID
                      ,SEGSTART) ANSLOGIN
     ,FIRST_VALUE(a.DIALED_NUM)
        IGNORE NULLS
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY UCID
                      ,SEGSTART
          ORDER BY
            CASE WHEN LENGTH(DIALED_NUM) > 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC
           ,SEGSTOP DESC) DIALEDNUM
     ,LAST_VALUE(a.transferred)
        IGNORE NULLS
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY UCID
                      ,SEGSTART) TRANSFER
     --MULTI ROW WINDOW MATCHES
     ,FIRST_VALUE(CALLID)
      IGNORE NULLS
      OVER(
        PARTITION BY UCID
                    ,SEGSTART
        ORDER BY ((DISPTIME + ANSHOLDTIME + talktime + RINGTIME) / 86400) DESC) CALLID
     ,FIRST_VALUE(a.acd)
      IGNORE NULLS
      OVER(
        PARTITION BY UCID
                    ,SEGSTART
        ORDER BY ((DISPTIME + ANSHOLDTIME + talktime + RINGTIME) / 86400) DESC) ACD
     ,first_VALUE(a.DISSPLIT)
      IGNORE NULLS
      OVER(
        PARTITION BY ucid
                    ,segstart
        ORDER BY ((DISPTIME + ANSHOLDTIME + talktime + RINGTIME) / 86400) DESC) DISSPLIT
     ,FIRST_VALUE(a.cmshost)
      IGNORE NULLS
      OVER(
        PARTITION BY UCID
                    ,SEGSTART
        ORDER BY ((DISPTIME + ANSHOLDTIME + talktime + RINGTIME) / 86400) DESC) CMSHOST
     ,FIRST_VALUE(anslogin)
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY ucid
          ORDER BY segstart ASC NULLS FIRST) COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN
     ,FIRST_VALUE(anslogin)
        IGNORE NULLS
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY ucid
          ORDER BY segstart ASC) COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN_NONULLS
     ,FIRST_VALUE(CALL_DTL_REC_ID)
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY ucid
          ORDER BY segstart ASC NULLS FIRST) COMPLEX_CALL_DTL_REC_ID
     ,ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY ucid
                      ,CASE
                         WHEN anslogin IS NOT NULL THEN ucid
                         ELSE anslogin
                       END
          ORDER BY segstart ASC) COMPLEX_RN_ANS
     ,first_VALUE(a.ASAIUUI)
        IGNORE NULLS
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY UCID
          ORDER BY CASE WHEN a.asaiuui IS NOT NULL THEN a.segstart END) COMPLEX_ASAIUUI
     ,ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY ucid
                      ,CASE WHEN origlogin IS NOT NULL THEN origlogin END
          ORDER BY segstart ASC) COMPLEX_RN_ORIG
     ,FIRST_VALUE(a.ORIGLOGIN)
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY UCID
                      ,to_char(
                         segstop
                        ,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24-MI-SS')) COMPLEX_ORIGLOGIN
     ,FIRST_VALUE(a.ORIGLOGIN)
        IGNORE NULLS
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY ucid
                      ,to_char(
                         segstop
                        ,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24-MI-SS')
          ORDER BY segstart ASC) COMPLEX_ORIGLOGIN_NONULLS
     ,FIRST_VALUE(anslogin)
        IGNORE NULLS
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY ucid
                      ,origlogin
          ORDER BY segstart DESC) COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN_ORIG
     ,LAST_VALUE(a.transferred)
        IGNORE NULLS
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY ucid
          ORDER BY segstart ASC) COMPLEX_TRANSFER
     --ASAIUUI WINDOW MATCHES
     ,LAST_VALUE(a.ASAIUUI)
        IGNORE NULLS
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY CALLID
                      ,acd
                      ,CASE
                         WHEN substr(
                                ASAIUUI
                               ,0
                               ,3) = '000' AND
                              asaiuui IS NOT NULL
                         THEN
                           1
                       END
          ORDER BY segstop) ASAIUUI_ASAIUUI
     ,LAST_VALUE(a.ORIGLOGIN)
        IGNORE NULLS
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY CALLID
                      ,SEGSTART
                      ,acd) ASAIUUI_ORIGLOGIN
     ,LAST_VALUE(a.ANSLOGIN)
        IGNORE NULLS
        OVER(
          PARTITION BY CALLID
                      ,SEGSTART
                      ,acd) ASAIUUI_ANSLOGIN
     FROM
     RDHONDT.TEMPAVAYA_PART a
     WHERE
      a.segstart BETWEEN '1-SEP-2019' AND '1-OCT-2019' --ucid = '00002108121561939226'
                                                       AND
      A.dissplit NOT IN (-1) AND
      a.acd IN (1
               ,2
               ,3))
SELECT
 *
FROM
( --SELECT THE PRI MATCH TYPE ***** HIGH QUERY COST... REVISIT
 SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) */
  t2.*
 ,row_number()
    OVER(
      PARTITION BY REC_ucid
                  ,rec_login
      ORDER BY
        CASE
          WHEN MATCHTYPE = 'UCID' THEN 1
          WHEN MATCHTYPE = 'UCID_MULTIPARTY' THEN 2
          WHEN MATCHTYPE = 'ASAIUUI' THEN 3
          WHEN MATCHTYPE = 'UCID_OUTBOUND' THEN 4
          WHEN MATCHTYPE = 'ORPHAN_SEGMENT' THEN 5
          WHEN matchtype = 'AM_SEGTIME' THEN 6
        END ASC
       ,transfer DESC) rn
 --UNION ALL THE MATCH TYPES
 FROM
 ( --!!!MATCH TYPE ASAIUU
  SELECT
   O.ucid ORIG_UCID
  ,d.ucid REC_UCID
  ,O.callid ORIG_CALLID
  ,d.callid REC_CALLID
  ,O.callstart ORIG_START
  ,o.callstop ORIG_STOP
  ,D.callstart REC_START
  ,o.callstop REC_STOP
  ,o.segstart ORIG_SEGSTART
  ,o.segstop ORIG_SEGSTOP
  ,d.segstart REC_SEGSTART
  ,d.segstop REC_SEGSTOP
  ,O.ASAIUUI_anslogin ORIG_LOGIN
  ,D.ASAIUUI_anslogin REC_LOGIN
  ,O.dissplit ORIG_SPLIT
  ,O.acd ORIG_ACD
  ,D.DISSPLIT REC_SPLIT
  ,D.acd REC_ACD
  ,D.CMSHOST REC_HOST
  ,O.cmshost ORIG_HOST
  ,D.DIALEDNUM DIALED_NUM
  ,CASE
     WHEN (D.callstop > O.callstop OR
           D.callstop > O.segstop OR
           d.segstop > o.segstop)
     THEN
       1
     ELSE
       0
   END TRANSFER
  ,'ASAIUUI' MATCHTYPE
  FROM
  ucid O
  INNER JOIN ucid D
    ON (D.segstart >= O.CALLSTART AND
        D.segstart <= O.CALLSTOP) AND
       substr(
         d.ASAIUUI_ASAIUUI
        ,-7
        ,7) = o.ASAIUUI_anslogin
  WHERE
   O.ASAIUUI_ANSLOGIN IS NOT NULL AND
   O.ASAIUUI_anslogin <> d.ASAIUUI_anslogin
  --!!!MATCH TYPE MULTIROW
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
   m.UCID
  ,m.REC_UCID
  ,m.ORIG_CALLID
  ,m.REC_CALLID
  ,m.ORIG_START
  ,m.ORIG_STOP
  ,m.REC_START
  ,m.REC_STOP
  ,m.orig_segstart
  ,m.orig_segstop
  ,m.rec_segstart
  ,m.rec_segstop
  ,m.ORIG_LOGIN
  ,m.REC_LOGIN
  ,m.ORIG_SPLIT
  ,m.ORIG_ACD
  ,m.REC_SPLIT
  ,m.REC_ACD
  ,m.REC_HOST
  ,m.ORIG_HOST
  ,m.DIALED_NUM
  ,CASE
     WHEN (m.REC_STOP > m.ORIG_STOP OR
           m.REC_STOP > m.ORIG_SEGSTOP OR
           m.REC_SEGSTOP > m.ORIG_SEGSTOP) OR
          (M.ORIG_SEGSTART = M.REC_SEGSTART AND
           M.ORIG_SEGSTOP = M.REC_SEGSTOP)
     THEN
       1
     ELSE
       0
   END TRANSFER
  ,m.MATCHTYPE
  FROM
  (SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) */
    t1.ucid
   ,max(ucid) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN ans_row = 1 THEN 1 END) rec_ucid
   ,max(complex_callid)
    KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
          ORDER BY
            CASE
              WHEN ORIG_ROW_MULTITRANSFER = 1 THEN 1
              WHEN orig_row = 1 THEN 2
            END) orig_callid
   ,max(complex_callid)
      KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN ans_row = 1 THEN 1 END) rec_callid
   ,max(callstart)
    KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
          ORDER BY
            CASE
              WHEN ORIG_ROW_MULTITRANSFER = 1 THEN 1
              WHEN orig_row = 1 THEN 2
            END) ORIG_start
   ,max(callstop)
    KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
          ORDER BY
            CASE
              WHEN ORIG_ROW_MULTITRANSFER = 1 THEN 1
              WHEN orig_row = 1 THEN 2
            END) ORIG_STOP
   ,max(segstart)
    KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
          ORDER BY
            CASE
              WHEN ORIG_ROW_MULTITRANSFER = 1 THEN 1
              WHEN orig_row = 1 THEN 2
            END) ORIG_SEGSTART
   ,max(segstop)
    KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
          ORDER BY
            CASE
              WHEN ORIG_ROW_MULTITRANSFER = 1 THEN 1
              WHEN orig_row = 1 THEN 2
            END) ORIG_SEGSTOP
   ,max(callstart)
      KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN ans_row = 1 THEN 1 END) REC_START
   ,max(callstop)
      KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN ans_row = 1 THEN 1 END) REC_stop
   ,max(segstart)
      KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN ans_row = 1 THEN 1 END) REC_segSTART
   ,max(segstop)
      KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN ans_row = 1 THEN 1 END) REC_segstop
   ,max(
      CASE
        WHEN ORIG_ROW_MULTITRANSFER = 1
        THEN
          origlogin
        WHEN orig_row = 1
        THEN
          CASE
            WHEN ANSLOGIN IS NOT NULL THEN anslogin
            WHEN origlogin IS NOT NULL THEN origlogin
          END
      END)
    KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
          ORDER BY
            CASE
              WHEN ORIG_ROW_MULTITRANSFER = 1
              THEN
                1
              WHEN orig_row = 1
              THEN
                CASE
                  WHEN ANSLOGIN IS NOT NULL THEN 2
                  WHEN origlogin IS NOT NULL THEN 3
                END
            END) ORIG_LOGIN
   ,max(anslogin)
      KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN ans_row = 1 THEN 1 END) REC_login
   ,max(dissplit)
    KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
          ORDER BY
            CASE
              WHEN ORIG_ROW_MULTITRANSFER = 1 THEN 1
              WHEN orig_row = 1 THEN 2
            END) ORIG_SPLIT
   ,max(acd)
    KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
          ORDER BY
            CASE
              WHEN ORIG_ROW_MULTITRANSFER = 1 THEN 1
              WHEN orig_row = 1 THEN 2
            END) ORIG_ACD
   ,max(dissplit)
      KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN ans_row = 1 THEN 1 END) REC_split
   ,max(acd) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN ans_row = 1 THEN 1 END) REC_acd
   ,max(cmshost)
      KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN ans_row = 1 THEN 1 END) REC_host
   ,max(cmshost)
    KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST
          ORDER BY
            CASE
              WHEN ORIG_ROW_MULTITRANSFER = 1 THEN 1
              WHEN orig_row = 1 THEN 2
            END) ORIG_HOST
   ,max(dialed_num)
    KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY CASE WHEN dial_row = 1 THEN DIALED_NUM END) DIALED_NUM
   ,'UCID_MULTIPARTY' MATCHTYPE
   FROM
   (SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) */
     d.ucid
    ,d.SEGSTART
    ,d.SEGSTOP
    ,d.DISSPLIT
    ,d.TRANSFERRED
    ,d.ACD
    ,D.CMSHOST
    ,d.n_ORIGLOGIN origlogin
    ,d.n_ANSLOGIN anslogin
    ,d.DIALED_NUM
    ,d.CALLING_PTY
    ,d.ASAIUUI
    ,d.callstart
    ,d.callstop
    ,d.call_dtl_rec_id test
    ,d.COMPLEX_ASAIUUI
    --if anslogin is blank on first call then select the first call rec in the ucid
    ,CASE
       WHEN (COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN IS NULL AND
             COMPLEX_CALL_DTL_REC_ID = d.call_dtl_rec_id) OR
            n_origlogin = substr(
                            COMPLEX_ASAIUUI
                           ,-7
                           ,7)
       THEN
         1
       ELSE
         CASE
           WHEN COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN IS NOT NULL AND
                n_anslogin IS NOT NULL
           THEN
             COMPLEX_RN_ANS
         END
     END ORIG_ROW
    ,CASE
       WHEN n_origlogin = substr(
                            COMPLEX_ASAIUUI
                           ,-7
                           ,7)
       THEN
         COMPLEX_RN_ORIG
     END ORIG_ROW_MULTITRANSFER
    --first anslogin is blank and row is the first non blank anslogin
    ,CASE
       WHEN COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN IS NULL AND
            n_anslogin = COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN_NONULLS
       THEN
         1
       ELSE
         --no origin login
         CASE
           WHEN n_origlogin IS NULL
           THEN
             --
             CASE
               WHEN n_anslogin IS NOT NULL AND
                    COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN = COMPLEX_ORIGLOGIN
               THEN
                 1
               ELSE
                 CASE
                   WHEN n_anslogin IS NOT NULL AND
                        COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN_nONULLS = n_anslogin AND
                        substr(
                          COMPLEX_ASAIUUI
                         ,-7
                         ,7) = COMPLEX_ORIGLOGIN
                   THEN
                     1
                   ELSE
                     CASE
                       WHEN n_anslogin IS NOT NULL AND
                            (COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN = d.n_origlogin OR
                             COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN = COMPLEX_ORIGLOGIN_NONULLS) AND
                            COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN_ORIG = d.n_ANSLOGIN
                       THEN
                         1
                     END
                 END
             END
           ELSE
             --ORIGLOGIN IS EQUAL TO FIRST ANSLOGIN (DIALED OUT) AND ITS THE FIRST
             CASE
               WHEN n_anslogin IS NOT NULL AND
                    COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN = d.n_origlogin AND
                    COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN = COMPLEX_ORIGLOGIN_NONULLS AND
                    COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN_ORIG = d.n_ANSLOGIN
               THEN
                 1
             END
         END
     END ANS_ROW
    ,CASE
       WHEN COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN IS NULL AND
            d.CALL_DTL_REC_ID = COMPLEX_CALL_DTL_REC_ID
       THEN
         1
       ELSE
         --DIALED OUT AND BY THE SAME LOGIN AS THE ANSROW LOGIN
         CASE
           WHEN n_origlogin = substr(
                                COMPLEX_ASAIUUI
                               ,-7
                               ,7)
           THEN
             1
           ELSE
             CASE
               WHEN n_origlogin IS NOT NULL AND
                    COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN = d.n_origlogin
               THEN
                 COMPLEX_RN_ORIG
             END
         END
     END DIAL_ROW
    ,CASE WHEN COMPLEX_ANSLOGIN IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE COMPLEX_TRANSFER END transfer
    ,COMPLEX_CALLID
    FROM
    ucid d) t1
   GROUP BY
   ucid) m
  --!!!MATCH TYPE UCID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(6) */
   O.ucid ORIG_UCID
  ,d.ucid REC_UCID
  ,O.callid ORIG_CALLID
  ,d.callid REC_CALLID
  ,O.callstart ORIG_START
  ,o.callstop ORIG_STOP
  ,D.callstart REC_START
  ,D.callstop REC_STOP
  ,o.segstart ORIG_SEGSTART
  ,o.segstop ORIG_SEGSTOP
  ,d.segstart REC_SEGSTART
  ,d.segstop REC_SEGSTOP
  ,O.anslogin ORIG_LOGIN
  ,D.anslogin REC_LOGIN
  ,O.dissplit ORIG_SPLIT
  ,O.acd ORIG_ACD
  ,D.DISSPLIT REC_SPLIT
  ,D.acd REC_ACD
  ,D.CMSHOST REC_HOST
  ,O.cmshost ORIG_HOST
  ,D.DIALEDNUM DIALED_NUM
  ,CASE
     WHEN (D.callstop > O.callstop OR
           D.callstop > O.segstop OR
           d.segstop > o.segstop)
     THEN
       1
     ELSE
       0
   END TRANSFER
  ,'UCID' MATCHTYPE
  FROM
  ucid D
  INNER JOIN ucid O
    ON (D.SEGSTART >= O.CALLSTART AND
        D.SEGSTART <= O.CALLSTOP + 0.00034722222) AND
       O.anslogin = D.origlogin
  WHERE
   O.ANSLOGIN IS NOT NULL AND
   D.ORIGLOGIN IS NOT NULL AND
   O.anslogin <> d.anslogin AND
   o.anslogin IS NOT NULL
  --!!!MATCH TYPE LOGIN_UNMATCHED

  UNION ALL
  SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(6) */
   O.ucid ORIG_UCID
  ,d.ucid REC_UCID
  ,O.callid ORIG_CALLID
  ,d.callid REC_CALLID
  ,O.callstart ORIG_START
  ,o.callstop ORIG_STOP
  ,D.callstart REC_START
  ,D.callstop REC_STOP
  ,o.segstart ORIG_SEGSTART
  ,o.segstop ORIG_SEGSTOP
  ,d.segstart REC_SEGSTART
  ,d.segstop REC_SEGSTOP
  ,O.ORIGlogin ORIG_LOGIN
  ,D.anslogin REC_LOGIN
  ,O.dissplit ORIG_SPLIT
  ,O.acd ORIG_ACD
  ,D.DISSPLIT REC_SPLIT
  ,D.acd REC_ACD
  ,D.CMSHOST REC_HOST
  ,O.cmshost ORIG_HOST
  ,D.DIALEDNUM DIALED_NUM
  ,CASE
     WHEN (D.callstop > O.callstop OR
           D.callstop > O.segstop OR
           d.segstop > o.segstop)
     THEN
       1
     ELSE
       0
   END TRANSFER
  ,'UCID_OUTBOUND' MATCHTYPE
  FROM
  ucid D
  INNER JOIN ucid O
    ON (D.SEGSTART >= O.CALLSTART AND
        D.SEGSTART <= O.CALLSTOP) AND
       O.ORIGLOGIN = D.origlogin
  WHERE
   O.ANSLOGIN IS NULL AND
   D.ORIGLOGIN IS NOT NULL AND
   O.ORIGLOGIN IS NOT NULL AND
   LENGTH(d.DIALED_NUM) <= 7
  UNION ALL
  SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(6) */
   NULL ORIG_UCID
  ,d.ucid REC_UCID
  ,NULL ORIG_CALLID
  ,d.callid REC_CALLID
  ,NULL ORIG_START
  ,NULL ORIG_STOP
  ,D.callstart REC_START
  ,D.callstop REC_STOP
  ,NULL ORIG_SEGSTART
  ,NULL ORIG_SEGSTOP
  ,d.segstart REC_SEGSTART
  ,d.segstop REC_SEGSTOP
  ,d.origlogin ORIG_LOGIN
  ,d.anslogin REC_LOGIN
  ,-1 ORIG_SPLIT
  ,-1 ORIG_ACD
  ,D.DISSPLIT REC_SPLIT
  ,D.acd REC_ACD
  ,D.CMSHOST REC_HOST
  ,'' ORIG_HOST
  ,D.DIALEDNUM DIALED_NUM
  ,0 TRANSFER
  ,'ORPHAN_SEGMENT' MATCHTYPE
  FROM
  ucid D
  WHERE
   D.ORIGLOGIN IS NOT NULL AND
   D.ANSLOGIN IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  ---test

  SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(6) */
   O.ucid ORIG_UCID
  ,d.ucid REC_UCID
  ,O.callid ORIG_CALLID
  ,d.callid REC_CALLID
  ,O.callstart ORIG_START
  ,o.callstop ORIG_STOP
  ,D.callstart REC_START
  ,d.callstop REC_STOP
  ,o.segstart ORIG_SEGSTART
  ,o.segstop ORIG_SEGSTOP
  ,d.segstart REC_SEGSTART
  ,d.segstop REC_SEGSTOP
  ,O.origlogin ORIG_LOGIN
  ,D.ANSLOGIN REC_LOGIN
  ,O.dissplit ORIG_SPLIT
  ,O.acd ORIG_ACD
  ,D.DISSPLIT REC_SPLIT
  ,D.acd REC_ACD
  ,D.CMSHOST REC_HOST
  ,O.cmshost ORIG_HOST
  ,O.DIALED_NUM DIALED_NUM
  ,CASE
     WHEN (D.callstop > O.callstop OR
           D.callstop > O.segstop OR
           d.segstop > o.segstop)
     THEN
       1
     ELSE
       0
   END TRANSFER
  ,'AM_SEGTIME' MATCHTYPE
  FROM
  ucid d
  INNER JOIN ucid o
    ON --call started no more than 60 seconds after origin
       o.segstart BETWEEN d.SEGSTART - INTERVAL '60' SECOND AND d.SEGSTART AND
       d.segstop BETWEEN o.segstop AND o.segstop + INTERVAL '60' SECOND AND
       --(o.segstop = d.callstop
       ((o.segstop = d.callstop OR
         o.segstop = d.segstop) OR
        (o.callstart BETWEEN d.SEGSTART - INTERVAL '5' SECOND AND d.SEGSTART AND
         d.segstop BETWEEN o.segstop AND o.segstop + INTERVAL '60' SECOND))
  WHERE
   d.dissplit IN (2619
                 ,2618
                 ,2614
                 ,428
                 ,137
                 ,2617
                 ,125
                 ,136
                 ,3067
                 ,127
                 ,2616
                 ,36) AND
   length(o.dialed_num) <= 8 -- the origin call is a dial out
                             AND
   o.origlogin IS NOT NULL AND
   o.anslogin IS NULL --the destination call is answered with an unknown origin
                      AND
   d.anslogin IS NOT NULL AND
   d.origlogin IS NULL AND
   o.split1 = -1 AND
   d.split1 <> -1) t2
 WHERE
  rec_login <> orig_login) t3
WHERE
 rn = 1
```

Plan:
[image]

Comment: holy lack of indents batman

Comment: I know it's horrible :( -- I need to adjust to a standard format.. if I use the auto formatting I lose the ability to read it quickly.. a bandaid I just need to rip off

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: "Don't sacrifice clarity for brevity when creating a minimal example. Use consistent naming and indentation, and include code comments if needed. Use your code editor’s shortcut for formatting code. Also, use spaces instead of tabs – tabs might not get correctly formatted on Stack Overflow."

Comment: hopefully it's at least a little better now.. thanks!

Comment: I guess that is an auto formater because it id not make it any easier for me to read except with CASE statements.  This question is also VERY long.  I think if you are interested in performance issues you should look at and include the execution plan.  Do you have that?

Comment: I use TOAD DP .. Probably a silly question.. but I've never figured out how to export my plans cleanly and paste onto stack overflow

Comment: In the spirit of the comments above, no one is going to be able to help you tuning something that big & ugly without having access to an explain plan at a minimum. My advice is to divide and conquer. Break it up into smaller queries, and find out where your greatest performance hit is. Tune it. Move on to the next worst performing subquery or function, and so forth. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: I added a picture of the plan.. hopefully that helps.. The biggest problem is that it runs quick with just 1-2 days of data.. the time comparison is always going to be within a couple hours of the original record.. I'm wondering if there's a way to do the window functions only over hours until of the entire date range.

Answer (score 1):

You have like random parallel hints on every select which not always help performance, then a whole bunch of queries, which I'd rather call in a procedure-like code, then insert them in some temporary table.

insert into table ... 
with ... select...  ; 
commit;
insert into table ... 
with select ... ; 
commit; 
and so on.

for the inline functions, I'd take min and max based on some condition.